# Clarification on how Codename One UITimer works

Tags: codenameone

I need a clarification about the Codename One `UITimer`.

For example, if I want to execute the same code every two seconds, a code like `UITimer.timer(2000, true, () -> { do something; });` works until the user stays in the current `Form`? Is that right?

If I want to execute the same code every two seconds **regardless the shown `Form`**, have I to use something different from `UITimer`, like a custom separate thread? For example the following code?

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
    hi.show();

    EasyThread.start("MyTimer").run(() -> {
        boolean executeMe = true;
        while (executeMe) {
            Log.p("Do something every two seconds...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Log.p("Stopping the EasyThread \"MyTimer\" because an exception");
                Log.e(ex);
                executeMe = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Moreover, if I execute this example code, the first logged line is:
`[MyTimer] 0:0:0,59 - Codename One revisions: 8b451ecb7bfbe60baf91006441e7d7d9c46afe09`
Why is that line logged by my custom thread instead of by the EDT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `UITimer` is an animation associated with the current `Form`. It doesn't draw anything but uses the builtin animation mechanism which runs on the EDT. Notice that if you leave a form and return to it the timer will continue e.g.:

- Opened form at 0 time and set a timer for 15 seconds
- Went to different form at 7 seconds
- Returned to original after 30 seconds - the timer will fire immediately on return

You can also use a regular `Timer` or `Thread`. However, for your specific code `EasyThread` doesn't provide a benefit over a regular thread since it runs in an infinite loop. The benefit of `EasyThread` is in it's job processing ability.

Notice that you would need to use `callSerially` to return to the EDT when working with such timers/threads.