# Will a UITimer automatically stop in Codenameone if form no longer in focus?

Tags: codenameone

If I use UItimer, does the timer and associated task get stopped when user navigates away from the bound form or does it continue indefinitely?

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53995646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The bound form is 100% responsible for the event. If you show a different `Form` or `Dialog` it will stop.